# CREATE Statement in PostgreSQL error relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql

My question is similar to the one posted earlier in the Community. questions/**62936399**/error-sql-state-42703-while-trying-to-insert-data-into-my-table

In PostgreSQL, I'm trying to run CREATE Table Statement so that I can continue with inserting values. Although my CREATE statement fails so I can't get on with INSERT statement. The error message that keeps coming up  ERROR:  relation "eventrequest" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01

I have re-did the entire CREATE Statement twice although the error message does not change.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CustNo         VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT CustNoNotNull NOT NULL, 
 CustName       VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT CustNameNotNull NOT NULL, 
 Address        VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT AddressNotNull NOT NULL, 
 Internal       CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT InternalNotNull NOT NULL, 
 Contact        VARCHAR(35) CONSTRAINT ContractNotNull NOT NULL, 
 Phone          VARCHAR(11) CONSTRAINT CPhoneNotNull NOT NULL, 
 City           VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT CityNotNull NOT NULL,
 State          VARCHAR(2) CONSTRAINT StateNotNull NOT NULL, 
 Zip            VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT ZipNotNull NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CustNo)
);



CREATE TABLE FACILITY
(FacNo          VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT FacNoNotNull NOT NULL, 
 FacName        VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT FacNameNotNull NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_FACILITY PRIMARY KEY (FacNo), 
 CONSTRAINT Unique_FacName UNIQUE(FacName)
);



CREATE TABLE LOCATION
(LocNo          VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT LocNoNotNull NOT NULL, 
 FacNo          VARCHAR(8), 
 LocName        VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT LocNameNotNull NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_LOCATION PRIMARY KEY (LocNo),
 CONSTRAINT FK_FACNO FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES FACILITY (FacNo) 
);



CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
  EmpNo             CHAR(11) CONSTRAINT EmpNoNotNull NOT NULL,
  EmpName           VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT EmpNameNotNull NOT NULL,
  Department        VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT DepartmentNotNull  NOT NULL,
  Email             VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT EmailNotNull NOT NULL,
  Phone             VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT PhoneNotNull  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo)
);


CREATE TABLE EVENTPLAN
(
  PlanNo        VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  EventNo       VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  workdate      DATE NOT NULL,
  notes         VARCHAR(40),
  activity      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  empno         VARCHAR(8),
  CONSTRAINT PK_PLANNO PRIMARY KEY (PlanNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_EVENTNO FOREIGN KEY (EventNo) REFERENCES EventRequest (EventNo)
);



CREATE TABLE EVENTREQUEST
(
  EventNo       VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  DateHeld      DATE NOT NULL,
  DateReq       DATE NOT NULL,
  FacNo         VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  CustNo        VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  DateAuth      DATE,
  Status        VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL CHECK (Status IN ('Pending', 'Denied', 'Approved')),
  EstCost       DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  EstAudience       INT NOT NULL CHECK (EstAudience > 0),
  BudNo         VARCHAR(8),
  CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTNO PRIMARY KEY (EventNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_FACILITYNOEVENTREQ FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Facility (FacNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMERNO FOREIGN KEY (CustNo) REFERENCES Customer (CustNo)
);



CREATE TABLE EVENTPLANLINE
(
  PlanNo    CHAR(8)   NOT NULL,
  LineNo    CHAR(8)   NOT NULL,
  LocNo     CHAR(8)   NOT NULL,
  ResNo     CHAR(8)   NOT NULL,
  TimeStart TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  TimeEnd   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  NumberFLD INTEGER   NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTPLANLINE PRIMARY KEY (PlanNo, LineNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_EVENTPLAN FOREIGN KEY (PlanNo) REFERENCES EventPlan (PlanNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_LOCATION FOREIGN KEY (LocNo) REFERENCES Location (LocNo),
  CONSTRAINT FK_RESOURCETBL FOREIGN KEY (ResNo) REFERENCES ResourceTbl (ResNo)
);



CREATE TABLE RESOURCETBL
(
  ResNo   CHAR(8)       NOT NULL,
  ResName VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
  Rate    DECIMAL(8, 2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_RESOURCETBL PRIMARY KEY (ResNo)
);
```

Comment: You need to change the order of the CREATE TABLE statements. You can reference a table (through a foreign key) that does not exist yet

Comment: Yes; that worked. I had to put both EventRequest and ResourceTbl - changed their order in CREATE Statement. Thanks heaps.